# 'Invalid character constant' error on a string

Tags: processing, string-comparison

In Processing 3, I am trying to compare two strings in an if/or statement:

```
 if ((firstSplit[6].equals('PPL')) || (firstSplit[7].equals('PPL'))) {
   //do stuff
 }
```

'firstSplit' is an array of strings. The first 'PPL' is underlined and the error that is shown is "Invalid character constant". Could anyone please explain this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Processing/Java, a String needs double quotes:

```
"PPL"
```

This is a char: `'c'`

This is a String: `"String"`

It's a bit more strict than JavaScript/Python/etc. in this aspect.

Comment: That makes sense. Incidentally, I've coded in Python more than I have in Java/Processing. Thanks!

Comment: This may be a bold statement, but as a rule of thumb, if the language you use is compiled (c/c++/java/etc.) use double quotes for strings. Even better, because you can use double quotes in Python/JS/etc., you can get into the habbit of using double quotes for Strings and rest assured it will work in the majority of cases